# Thinkpad X240 acpi status "Unknown"

Tags: linux, acpi

This is the results of `acpi`

```
Battery 0: Unknown, 79%
Battery 1: Unknown, 75%
```

I didn't realize since when this happened, but it used to be okay. I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-59.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Probably driver problem. First I would do a kernel upgrade. But https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://superuser.com would be a better match for this question.